# SpringBoot 2 debug using the Gradle plugin

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I am trying to remote debug a Spring Boot 2.0 web application, built and run with the new Spring Boot Gradle plugin. I've read that the way to go is to pass the `--debug-jvm` option like so:

```
./gradlew bootRun --debug-jvm
```

But I get the following:

```
Problem configuring task :bootRun from command line.
> Unknown command-line option '--debug-jvm'.
```

Has something changed in Spring Boot 2.0 or am I missing something? The [new gradle plugin reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/gradle-plugin//reference/html/) does not mention anything regarding debug.

I am running Spring Boot and spring-boot-gradle-plugin version 2.0.0.M6, gradle version 4.3.1.

Comment: Try using `gradle bootRun -Dorg.gradle.debug=true`. Looks like it runs with remote debugging enabled but I was unable to setup my IDE correctly so I am not 100% sure it is something you expect.

Comment: I think this mode enables debugging for the gradle script itself, but not for the spring boot application. After attaching the debugger, execution never stops on my breakpoints in the actual Spring Boot application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following would work:

1. Edit build.gradle

   `bootRun {
     jvmArgs = ["-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000,suspend=n"]
   }`
2. Execute`./gradlew bootRun`
3. Attach the debugger after the Spring Boot application has started (port 8000 in the specific case)